# Flow doesn't change volume

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory

Given an autonomous equation $y'=f(y) \in \mathbb{R} ^m$, where $\mathrm{div} f=0$ for whole domain of equation. Show that flow $\phi^t$ of this equation doesn't change volume, ie. whenever $\phi^t$ is defined on a measurable set $E$ then $\mathrm{Vol} \left(\phi^t\left(E\right) \right) = \mathrm{Vol} \left(E\right) $.

I have tried doing it by some kind of change of variables in integration, knowing that $\phi^t$ is a diffeomorphism, but I couldn't finish it off.

Comment: Hint: show that $\frac{d}{dt}\det(\Phi^t)=0$.

Comment: @Mindlack I might be wrong on this one but isn't $\phi^t \mathbb{R}^m$? How can I calculate the determinant then?

Comment: you’re right, it’s $d\Phi^t$ (the spatial derivative at some given point) instead of $\Phi^t$.

Comment: I don't really know what to do here and even if $\frac{d}{dt} \det(d\Phi^t)=0$ I do not know what it gives me.

Comment: If $\frac{d}{dt}\det(d\Phi^t)=0$, then $\det(d\Phi^t)=1$ at each $t$ and then you can apply the change of variable formula.

Answer (score 0):

As the point dynamic is approximately $y(t+dt)=y(t)+f(y(t))dt$, the tangent space is propagated over the time step $dt$ via the linear map $I+f'(y)dt$. The volume change is the determinant of that matrix, and
$$
\det(I+f'(y)dt)=1+{\rm tr}(f'(y))dt+O(dt^2)=1+{\rm div}(f)_{y(t)}dt+O(dt^2)
$$